# List of approvers for a suggested edit is incorrect in 10k tools

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

Take a look at the following suggested edit review on Anime.SE: [link](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4935). As you can see, users "debal" and "Dimitri mx" approved it, and user "Shinobu Oshino" rejected it.

If you go into the 10k tools (well, 2k tools), you will find that the [suggested edit stats](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits) ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLtQJ.png)) claim that the edit was "approved by senshin, Dimitri mx, debal, Shinobu Oshino 18 hours ago".

Since I took no action on the suggested edit, it is strange that I am listed as one of the users that approved it. This looks like a bug. (I believe that I *did* skip that review, which might be why my name is listed there.)